# date equivalent of current day from last year c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an asp.net project in which I need to find the date equivalent of current day from last year?.

Suppose if current year date is "02/26/2015 " then last year date would be "02/27/2015  ".

It is working fine if we write this code

```
return cyDate.AddYears(-1).AddDays(1);
```

But it is not working properly if the year is a leap year. So I fixed this by using the following code

```
 if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(cyDate.Year) && ((cyDate.Month > 2) ||  ((cyDate.Month == 2)  && cyDate.Day >= 29 )))
            {
                return cyDate.AddYears(-1).AddDays(2);
            }
            else
            {
                return cyDate.AddYears(-1).AddDays(1);
            }
```

**Is there any other suitable way to do this ? I searched, but did't find any proper answer for this. Please help me on this.**

Comment: Why would February 27-th be an equivalent of February 26-th?

Comment: *Why* would the "last year date" be Feb 27th instead of Feb 26th? That makes no sense to me. Please define "date equivalent" for us.

Comment: ...and in the same year?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake. It is 02/27/2015

Comment: It is not date equivalent. It is day equivalent. If the current day is  in friday, previous year day must be in friday

Comment: According to your last comment, `cyDate.AddDays(-364)`

Comment: No. I think it will get a wrong value if the year is a leap year

Comment: What @IvanStoev provided is correct, even in leap year case, unless in that case you don't want to match day-of-week.  Leap years don't change multiples of 7.

Comment: Yae. But when I doing this, I got 1 week difference ie. I tried 17/3/2015 then I got 11/3/2014. But it should be 18/3/2014 right ?

Comment: @Vishnu `new DateTime(2015, 3, 17).AddDays(-364)` => #3/18/2014# In general what you are asking for is undefined. There is no such thing like `the current day from last year`. Your calc and the equivalent mine answer   the question `what was the date before 52 weeks`

Answer (score 1):

DayOfYear is a DateTime concept of # of days this year, so it is an integer value between 1 and 366.

I think you maybe want to use that concept.

Of course, since I don't understand why you would want this data, I am a little unsure of exactly the best way to get it.

If you really want a day 365 days ago, just do that.

```
DateTime oneYearAgo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-365)
```

If you really want today's date, but last year plus one day, just do that.

```
DateTime oneYearAgo = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddDays(1)
```

Why do you believe your logic should change based on the leap year or not leap year?  I strongly suggest you double check your requirements, and if they are as complex as you suggest they are, then there is nothing wrong with writing a slightly complex routine to calculate that date.